# What are concrete steps to simultaneously 2 apps on tomcat in IntelliJ?

Tags: spring, tomcat, intellij-idea

I have a *Spring Boot* app which writes to an *ActiveMQ* topic. Another application is a Spring Boot listener that reads from this topic. I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Ultimate Edition).

What are concrete steps to allow me to run both apps simultaneously on *Tomcat 8.0.24*?

I have tried changing Tomcat port from `8080` to `8081` and JMX port from `1099` to `1098` and setting a different debugger port for each application. I have also tried using an IntelliJ IDEA compound configuration and making a copy of the Tomcat install with all different ports in `server.xml`. I keep getting various errors like `address is in use - bindException` and `cannot use debugger port. socket closed`.

Comment: A copy of Tomcat with different ports in `server.xml` definitely works for me, please double check.

Comment: Note that, by default, tomat listens on 8080, 8005, 8009. Check your server.xml

Answer (score 0):

Under Intellij run configurations - create two different tomcat settings (i usually name it with the port number so its easy to identity tomcat-8080 and tomcat-8005), change ports on one of them.

- http
- jmx
- shutdown

Comment: Which port is shutdown? Is it the AJP port or the port seen under 'Debug' in Startup/Connection tab in Run/Debug configurations?

Comment: can you try with updating http and jmx ports?, it looks like intellij is taking care of shutdown ports if two separate configurations are created.

Comment: Changing http and jmx ports did not work for me. Both projects are open in separate IntelliJ IDEA windows which means they are in separate Run/Debug configurations? - at least they are created and named differently

Comment: can you also please try changing the <connector> port in <tomcat-install -directory>/conf/server.xml ?